# Convert string timestamp to time_t in c++

Tags: c++, datetime

I'm receiving a string, containing an date and time

But when I convert the string to `time_t`, something goes wrong

It prints out: "Sun Dec 31 00:00:00" but it should be "Thu Jan 25 10:00:00"

I tried this code, and I want it to print out Thu Jan 25 10:00:00

```
const char* datetimeString;
struct tm tmStruct; 
static const char* dtFormat = "MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss";
datetimeString = "01-25-2024 10:00:00";
strptime(datetimeString, dtFormat, &tmStruct);
    
time_t dtStart = mktime(&tmStruct);
cout<<ctime(&dtStart);
```

Comment: If you read the description of the `strptime` library function, it will tell you exactly how to figure out where the problem is. Did you read it? Did you notice how this function's return value is described? Is there anything in that description that's unclear to you?

Answer (score 0):

`ctime()` takes in a `time_t` representing the number of seconds elapsed since the epoch: `1970-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 (UTC)`.

Your call to `ctime()` is returning a string representing a time before that epoch, which means your input `time_t` value must be a negative value.

And in fact, `mktime()` returns `-1` on failure when "the specified broken-down time cannot be represented as calendar time (seconds since the Epoch)".  But you are not checking for that condition.

You are also not checking the return value of `strptime()` for failure to make sure the returned `tmStruct` is valid.  And indeed, your call to `strptime()` is failing, because your `format` string is malformed.  It needs to be like this instead:

```
static const char* dtFormat = "%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S";
```

Now, that being said, since you are using C++, consider using C++'s own date/time utilities, such as [`std::get_time()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/get_time) and [`std::put_time()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/put_time), eg:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctime>

std::string datetimeString = "01-25-2024 10:00:00";
std::tm tmStruct; 
std::istringstream(datetimeString) >> std::get_time(&tmStruct, "%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S");    

std::cout << << std::put_time(&tmStruct, "%c");
```